How do I stop the paint bubbling off and concrete cap?
I have a concrete cap that was painted by the house developer. Water falls from the deck above on to it so the paint has chipped off. The developer has sanded and re-painted the concrete cap using epoxy but that has also now bubbled off. Unfortunately what was once smooth is now rougher due to the sanding. What's a good solution to protect the concrete and avoid further erosion? Is there a solution that use the same color vs. being clear to cover up the rough concrete? Should we use some kind of sealer. Here's a link to an image: https://imgur.com/a/QLpLJvz

could be stone I guess. but looks a lot like concrete.

A good paint should not peel like you have.
Scrape off the peeled paint. Repaint with an epoxy primer and epoxy paint. You will probably have to go to a paint store (not big box) to get the proper paint.
If the epoxy peels off whatever is dripping is some type of acid and not rainwater.

A good, straight forward answer to a simple,common problem.

I think "primer" is the key word here. Surface prep is vital, and all too often overlooked (especially by corner-cutting developers).
